# PHP IF AND OR breaking with second OR

Tags: php

I have a loop which I echo out the number of the item using:

```
$i = 1;
[content]
$i++;
```

Within my content I am trying to get an if statement to work based off the value of `$i`

```
if ($user_id == 2 and $i != 1 || $i != 2 ) {

}
```

If I leave out this part: `|| $i != 2` it works however with it the script fails and returns true.

How am I able to get it working with both 1 and 2 values?

Comment: use `()` to enforce YOUR desired parsing order? right now you're letting php pick the order according to its own [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). Get into the habit of ALWAYS specifying `()` regardless of whether the default order is what you want or not. then you don't have to worrya bout remembering the precedence rules for whatever language you're in and can enforce your desired order always.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if ($user_id == 2 && $i != 1 && $i != 2 )`?

Comment: `if ($user_id == 2 and ($i != 1 || $i != 2) )` - *I think*. If not, I'll take the bullet ;-) so shoot me!

Comment: @Fred -ii- That didn't work unfortunately :/

Comment: @JonStirling You've been ripped off below - just a slight difference of `&&` to `and`

Comment: @BenH what about Jon's suggestion? He did put it up first before that answer below.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `imitation is the sincerest form of flattery` ;)

Comment: @JonStirling if you could post yours as an answer I would mark yours correct as you posted first. thank you :)

Comment: @JonStirling *Aye*, so true :-)

Comment: @BenH Personally, I'd of asked Jon to submit it as an answer here, seeing what you posted in the answer below. It's only fair, I find ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- See my above comment. Already asked :)

Comment: It's fine, I don't have the motivation to write up a proper explanation of the _why_ behind my comment which I feel posting an answer would deserve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Overview**

I'd use `&&` instead of `and`, and it's good to always organise your more complex `IF` statements with parentheses so that

a) aesthetically you can see the parsing order
  b) you can manually set the parsing order, especially if different from PHP's priority

---

**Correction**

That being said:

You want the condition to fire if

1. `$user_id` is `2` AND `$i` is NOT `1`, or
2. `$i` is NOT `2`

So you can do:

```
if( ($user_id == 2 && $i != 1) || ($i != 2) ){
    //...
```

Here you can see the two commands are separated by enclosing them in their own parentheses.

---

**Proof**

1. `$i = 1` and `$user_id = 1`: the first bracket is `false`, the second bracket is `true`, the condition fires
2. `$i = 1` and `$user_id = 2`: the first bracket is `false`, the second bracket is `true`, the condition fires
3. `$i = 2` and `$user_id = 1`: the first bracket is `false`, the second bracket is `false`, the condition doesn't fire
4. `$i = 2` and `user_id = 2`: the first bracket is `true`, the second bracket is `false`, the condition fires

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want is the and operator again.

```
if ($user_id == 2 and $i != 1 and $i != 2 ) {
    ...
}
```

You need all of those conditions to be true in order to execute the contents of the if block, so and is the operator you need.

Comment: This might bite back.

Comment: Ahh okay! I thought it would have to be 2 and 1 or 2 as i thought 2 and 1 and 2 would mean $i has two values. my mistake!

Comment: @Fred-ii- Please explain. What is the issue?

Comment: @BenH Glad to help. It may be worthwhile reviewing logic truth tables. Also if you found my answer helpful, please consider upvoting :)